# Pre processadores e como trabalhar com eles

Tags: coffeescript, preprocessador, pug, stylus

Olá pessoal da comunidade, tenho duvida de como trabalhar com pre processadores, afinal terei que reescrever o codigo duas vezes ? ou terei que copiar e colar em um convertor online ? tenho mto enteresse em utilizar pug, stylus e coffee para usar em meus projetos porem não sei como e se há a possibilidade de fazer eles se compilarem para html e css e js sem ter que ficar copiando e colando em convertores!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, existem vários automatizadores com plugins de pre-processadores facilmente configuráveis. Gulp e Grunt acredito que sejam os mais conhecidos.

Configurando ele, você deixa o código de desenvolvimento em uma pasta chamada /assets/src/** e o automatizador gerar um novo código otimizado, comprimido e etc em uma outra pasta como por exemplo /assets/dist/**.

Claro que isso é uma exemplo!

Tem como encontrar vários tutoriais por ai, mas deixo aqui o conteúdo  criado no tableless.

GULP: https://tableless.com.br/gulp-o-novo-automatizador/

GRUNT: https://tableless.com.br/grunt-voce-deveria-estar-usando/

Comment: Muito legal o conteudo Mailon era esse o tipo de conteudo que estava com dificuldade de achar. Obrigado!